# Is there any Dart implementation for Casl JS?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, casl

Is there any dart implementation for [casl.js](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/) to use it with flutter project?

Comment: No, there is no one. Probably there will be one for Rust to be more portable